# MacBook Pro starts with "Installing onto SSD"

Tags: bootcamp, recovery, startup

MacBook Pro Retina mid 2014 13" macOS catalina 10.15.2 I believe. Suddenly during startup it goes into some grey mode and says "Installing onto SSD".

I've not seen this mode before. Will it erase my files? I have shut it down using the power button because I didn't want to overwrite personal stuff... Any idea why this mode comes up?

I have used Windows 10 Bootcamp on an external drive, which I have disconnected, and also another external drive, now disconnected. Maybe it's related. Also when I do Cmd+R it goes into internet OS installation. Would that erase my files or is it safe to continue?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's just upgrading to Catalina. Normally an update doesn't overwrite your files. Presumably you must have triggered the update yourself at some point? Shutting down during an installation is a bad idea. 
Anyway, you should always have a backup so that if anything gets accidentally deleted, you won't lose it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks but I earlier Catalina updates didn't look like this I don't think. I already had Catalina but perhaps this is an update again. I know it's not great to shut it down during installation, I panicked. I'm letting it run now, hopefully it will work...

Answer (score 1):

It was just the update to Catalina 10.15.3!